# youtube upload issue using rest api from c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

I am trying to run a youtube api test fro video upload, with my following test method,

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task uploadVideoToYoutube()
    {
        var actualAccessor = new YouTubeServiceAccessor();
      //  var x = actualAccessor.UploadVideo("E:/Old LAP Files/Downloads/mpegvideo.mpg", "ya29.Glw3BpdZiXYlMSSDWkhUlm2lGlm9EtWueQnT3RCixl6ErvwQthHQ9-PbstdA29GhV9hvEd25MYsoqiHUsidunxtXw3AEQ4huTUPPzxtE0ilgp3hs5YQdDBnf_jvH0A");

        //var myclient = new Accessors.Services.BigIronCore.HttpClient();
        var token = "your token here";
        var filePath = @"E:/Old LAP Files/Downloads/mpegvideo.mpg";
        var client =  new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            using (var sr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var request = new YoutubeRequest();
                request.Snippet = new YoutubeSnippet();
                request.Snippet.Title = "Test of upload video"; 
                request.Snippet.Description="Test of upload video";
                request.Status = new YoutubeStatus();
                request.Status.PrivacyStatus = "private";

                request.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";

                try
                {
                    var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                    var json = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    content.Add(json);

                    var sc = new StreamContent(sr);
                    sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    content.Add(sc);



                    //var responsepost = await client.PostAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status", content);
                    var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=status&mine=true&access_token={token}");

                    var responseupload = await client.PostAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status", content);                       
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
        }
            }
```

I am getting succees for the first api

```
var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=status&mine=true&access_token={token}");
```

but i am not able to upload video into youtube using the other api belo it, i am getting 400 error (bad request),

My token is valid thts y im getting success for the other api,

How i can upload video using the same method?
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any Nuget packages? If so please mention them as I can't reproduce your problem without them

Comment: no im not using any . YoutubeRequest, YoutubeStatus all are manual class i created. just http.client

Comment: using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

Comment: Here is a C# .NET example from YouTube itself https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet . I recommend using their classes and their Nuget packages (Google.Apis.Auth and Google.Apis.Youtube.v3)

Comment: mine was a working peice of code, recently started  getting bad request

Comment: in the link you provide, if u have a token already generated, how to use it? and what is where to provide our username and password of youtube?

Comment: The username and password come from a .json file and are not saved within the code itself (`FileStream("client_secrets.json"...`) and why not just call the OAuth2 API to generate a key? This a lot safer

Comment: i already have a generated token, is there any way to use it?

Comment: I think your API Token has timed out and is invalid, go to this site: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=your_token` and replace `your_token` with the API token and see what it says

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181923/discussion-between-vishnuprasad-kv-and-mindswipe).